# How can I distribute an EXE file from a web browser download without triggering any warnings?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

For a Java desktop application, I am using Launch4J to create an EXE file, and [NSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) to create an installer.

It works fine all the while, but until recently the Chrome and [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) browsers both give a download warning

> ...exe is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous

It looks as follows.

### Chrome

[image]

---

### Edge

[image]

---

### The old version 1.0.7.56 doesn't have any issue

My previous version of download (version 1.0.7.56) doesn't flag any warning

https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/releases/download/release_1-0-7-56/jstock-1.0.7.56-setup.exe

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/1eebb22b116c02e36c3aa4d4311608d2843694da378e8654f5f3d83fb41ca655 (Virus total report for version 1.0.7.56)

---

### The new version 1.0.7.57 has a download warning issue

My current version of download (version 1.0.7.57) will flag an unwanted warning

https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/releases/download/release_1-0-7-57/jstock-1.0.7.57-setup.exe

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/2b32d07deba2e932dc1e44120c09efb6152556f94bbb6fef87d22f438c1a64fb (Virus total report for version 1.0.7.57)

---

What are some good ways to remove such blockage from the web browser, so that my users can download those EXE files without any issue?

Comment: Did you sign the `.exe` with AuthentiCode (`signtool.exe`)? (If not, you will need to sign it with a certificate from an AuthentiCode certificate vendor, [and they aren't cheap](https://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-authenticode-certificates.html).

Comment: Signing might help but there is no real workaround other than many people downloading to increase the files reputation. This is just the world we live in now. It is hard to be a small time developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because it's an unfamiliar downloaded EXE file. I think the only way to remove that is to request a review.

For Edge, you can try to click **Report this file as safe** to report the download.

[image]

For Chrome, Google maintains a list of trusted software publishers. If you're a software publisher and your binaries are flagged by Chrome, learn [how to resolve malware or unwanted software issues](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249) related to your downloads.